# Text not showing in Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I've been stuck on this question for a while, the text in textbox shows in the visualiser but not when I run the program. Can anyone please help me?

```
 <TextBox x:Name="SearchKey" Text ="hello"  BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto" Background="White" Margin="21.724,4,20.999,4">
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
            Command="{Binding SearchTemplatesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:EmailComposerWindow}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchKey}"
         />
      <KeyBinding Key="Esc"
       Command="{Binding ResetSearchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:EmailComposerWindow}}}"
         />
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
  </TextBox>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything; could any code-behind be overwriting it?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET BLESS! A method that someone else wrote was resetting it to be a blank string each time.